# FB.api dont work when redirected to the other .aspx page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using pure facebook javascript api in asp.net. I have done the authentication in one asp.net page. All facebook api calls in that page and when i redirect to the other asp.net page no facebook api call works. Can any one let me knw why is it this and whats the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Facebook script included in those other pages, and only included one. Also make sure those pages are using the correct app id.